# Is there a simpler way to display this Java UI?

Tags: java, swing, layout, user-interface, awt

I want to display a line of text with a button underneath it, both of which are centered horizontally and vertically. I currently have a `BoxLayout` containing a `JLabel`, a rigid area for spacing and then a `JButton` within a `JPanel`. This seems quite complicated for what I want to do and also when the window size is changed, both the text and the button are no longer centered. Is there a better way to do this?

```
----------------------
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|      ________      |
|      | Text |      |
|      --------      |
|      ________      |
|      |Button|      |
|      --------      |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
----------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a 2x1 [GridLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with something like:

```
JButton btn = new JButton("I'm a Button");
JLabel lbl = new JLabel("I'm a Label");

JPanel pan = new JPanel();
pan.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pan, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

pan.add(lbl);
pan.add(btn);

JPanel pan2 = new JPanel();
pan2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pan2, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

pan2.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
pan2.add(pan);
pan2.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(pan2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

It's still a bit complex, and you'd probably want to add another panel for the label so that it's centered, UIs in my experience tend to be a lot of work to layout.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Centered Components]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class CenteredComponents {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
                JLabel l = new JLabel("Centered Text", SwingConstants.CENTER);
                gui.add(l);
                // the GBL allows us to center a component
                JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                p.add(new JButton("Centered Button"));
                gui.add(p);

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Centered Components");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setContentPane(gui);
                f.pack();
                f.setSize(350,150);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

### Update

> I need both components to stay vertically centered when the window is maximised

[image: Centered Components 2]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class CenteredComponents {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
                // the GBL allows us to center a component..
                JPanel center = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                JLabel l = new JLabel("Centered Text", SwingConstants.CENTER);
                gui.add(l);
                gui.add(new JButton("Centered Button"));
                // ..in this case the component is a panel
                center.add(gui);

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Centered Components");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setContentPane(center);
                f.pack();
                f.setSize(350,150);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great, except that I need both components to stay vertically centered when the window is maximised.

Comment: I thought my code implemented that spec.  DYM they should stay *together* and vertically centered?  That is easy.  Put both components in the GL panel 1st, then add **that** panel to the GBL.  It would help immensely in layout questions, if you provided ASCII art of the GUI before and after change in size.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know for next time to provide an ASCII image. However, now the components stretch the width of the window. Is it possible to shrink them to fit?

Comment: Yes, yes it is.  Provide that ASCII art, and I'll see what needs doing.

Comment: Which part of *"provided ASCII art of the GUI before **and after** change in size"* are you having trouble understanding?  That is **two** (count them, **2**) ASCII arts.  What good is 1?  OTOH 1) I took a random guess (something I don't usually do) that you meant exactly what I posited in my first comment. 2) I'm pretty much at the end of the help I will offer (see edit) on a question that was previously marked as answered.